# Jade/Bootstrap + Nodejs: Grid rendering columns incorrectly

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

New at using Jade/Bootstrap and trying to apply the grid system in a nodejs/express set up.  My intended page has a top bar, a page header below it, and then two columns below that.  I read the html examples and then translated the ideas to jade.  The Jade code below vertically stacks page-header, page content, and secondary page content (see index.jade).  What was expected is that the latter two would be side-by-side.  So far: all css and script files are being loaded properly as seen using 'nodemon', I've verified indentation in Jade, I've read through various Bootstrap documentation, and looked for similar problems here in Stack.  The rendering actually looks like its being formatted for a small screen.  What am I doing wrong?

layout.jade

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',  type='text/css', href='stylesheets/custom.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet',  type='text/css', href='stylesheets/style.css')

    script(type='text/javascript', src='lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  body

    block content
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
    div.topbar
        div.fill
            div.container
                a.brand(href='#') #{title}
                ul.nav
                    li.active
                        a(href='#') Home
                    li
                        a(href='#about') About
                    li
                        a(href='#contact') Contact
                form.pull-right(method="post", id="loginForm")
                    input.input-small(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Username")
                    input.input-small(id="password", type="password", name="Password", placeholder="Password")
                    input.btn.primary(type="submit", value="Sign In")
                p#loginPrompt.pull-right.login-prompt
    div.container
        div.content
            div.page-header
                h1 Main Page
                small Welcome to #{title}
            div.row
                div.span4 
                    h2 Page Content
                div.span4
                    h3 Secondary Content
        div.footer
            p &copy; test 2013
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?  In 3 your class should be like `col-`, as in `col-md-4`, instead of `span4`. [SO post on the version differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952571/how-has-twitter-bootstrap-3-changed-over-version-2-3-2). If this is your problem, let me know and I'll post as answer.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud ... that's exactly it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 made some changes that renamed some key classes, including the `span` classes, so you'll need to use `col-` instead, as in `col-md-4`:

```
div.row
    div.col-md-4
        h2 Page Content
    div.col-md-4
        h3 Secondary Content
```

or even something like this, if you want it to be one column for phones, and two for others:

```
div.row
    div.col-xs-12.col-sm-4
        h2 Page Content
    div.col-xs-12.col-sm-4
        h3 Secondary Content
```

[SO post on version differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952571/how-has-twitter-bootstrap-3-changed-over-version-2-3-2).

Comment: Best link is: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration  Frustrating situation esp. since I was following recent tutorials [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-handling-complex-designs/) whose links, it turns out, all pointed to v2 documentation.

Comment: @kimbellinger good link. Yes I have same problem with node tutorials using older versions of Express :/ Keeps it interesting I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
row
col-md-4
    h2 Page Content
col-md-4
    h3 Secondary Content
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.